# Searching values in dataframe using re.search

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

I have a lot of datasets that I need to iterate through, search for specific value and return some values based on search outcome.

Datasets are stored as dictionary:

```
key     type         size       Value
df1     DataFrame    (89,10)    Column names:
df2     DataFrame    (89,10)    Column names:
df3     DataFrame    (89,10)    Column names:
```

Each dataset looks something like this, and I am trying to look if value in column A row 1 has 035 in it and return B column.

```
|   A     |    B    |    C    
 02 la 035    nan      nan
   Target      7        5 
   Warning     3        6
```

If I try to search for specific value in it I get an error

```
TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern
```

I have tried:

```
something = []

for key in df:
    text = df[key]
    if re.search('035', text):
         something.append(text['B'])
            
Something = pd.concat([something],  axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.str.contains()` : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A":["02 la 035", "Target", "Warning"],
    "B":[0,7,3],
    "C":[0, 5, 6]
})
df[df["A"].str.contains("035")] # Returns first row only.
```

Also works for regex.

```
df[df["A"].str.contains("[TW]ar")] # Returns last two rows.
```

**EDIT to answer additional details.**

The dataframe I set up looks like this:

[image]

To extract column B for those rows which match the last regex pattern I used, amend the last line of code to:

```
df[df["A"].str.contains("[TW]ar")]["B"]
```

This returns a series. Output:

[image]

Edit 2: I see you want a dataframe at the end. Just use:

```
df[df["A"].str.contains("[TW]ar")]["B"].to_frame()
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer, I have updated the question. Could you please take a look? Please tell me if something is not understandable.

Comment: @Dino: Sorry. I answered the question as asked and your edits are effectively a new question.